# SDKClientException: Connection Reset

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, proxy, amazon-iam, aws-sts

We are connecting to S3 via AssumeRole from multiple microservices in our application. The services run inside docker and try to reach S3 via proxy. However, the connection succeeds for 8 out of 9 services, whereas for one particular service we are getting SdkClientException : Could not execute HTTP request - Connection reset.

The Dockerfile for the services are like below:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim

ENV HTTPS_PROXY 'http://proxyip:proxyport' 
ENV HTTP_PROXY 'http://proxyip:proxyport'
ENV https_proxy 'http://proxyip:proxyport'
ENV http_proxy 'http://proxyip:proxyport

RUN apt -y update && apt -y upgrade
RUN apt -y install unzip
RUN apt -y install curl
RUN apt -y install less
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
RUN unzip awscliv2.zip
RUN ./aws/install

VOLUME ~/.aws:/root/.aws
WORKDIR /tmp
ENV NO_PROXY 'someip'
ENV no_proxy 'someip'
ARG JAVA_OPTSENV JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS
COPY services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT java $JAVA_OPTS -Dagentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5006 -XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=~/jvm-us.log -jar services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active="test-profile"
```

We are trying to establish connection S3 from our services using `STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider class`, the code is as below:

```
@Bean(name = "awsCredentialsProvider")
public AWSCredentialsProvider getAWSCredentials() {
    BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAWSCredentials);

}

@Bean
public AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient() {
    AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(getAWSCredentials())
            .withRegion(region)
            .build();
    return stsClient;
}

@Bean(name = "awsS3AudioBucket")
public String getAWSS3AudioBucket() {
    return bucket;
}


@Bean(name = "region")
public String getRegion() {
    return region;
}

public AWSSessionCredentialsProvider getAWSSTSCredentials() throws Exception {
    AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = null;
    log.info("Role Arn for the connection is: " + roleArn);
    AWSSessionCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder(roleArn, "session-s3-access")
            .withStsClient(stsClient()).build();
    log.info("Credentials obtained and the token is: " + awsCredentialsProvider.getCredentials().getSessionToken());

    return awsCredentialsProvider;
}
```

8 out of our 9 services are able to connect to S3 and we are able to get the session token. However for one service we are getting the SdkClientException - Connection reset issue. Has anyone been able to fix such errors?

```
aws-java-sdk-sts - version 1.11.174
Java version - 11
```

Error logs:

```
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3]: Factory method 'amazonS3' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Please add your Dockerfile as the plain text format not as an image

Comment: Added the DockerFile inline.